# Oracle Rank by Recent Dates to retrieve relative week number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with this data ;

```
ID      Date_Weekly_List
1       12/08/2014
2       12/08/2014
3       12/08/2014
4       07/08/2014
5       07/08/2014
6       06/08/2014
```

And would like to receive a result set that groups the rows by weekly list, most recent date first;

```
ID      Date_Weekly_List    Rank
1       12/08/2014          1
2       12/08/2014          1
3       12/08/2014          1
4       07/08/2014          2
5       07/08/2014          2
6       06/08/2014          3
```

I have tried to use the Rank function partitioning and ordering by date_weekly_list but this always returns 1 as the rank, where am I going wrong ?

```
select id, date_weekly_list, rank() over (partition by date_weekly_list order by date_weekly_list     desc)
from my_table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to remove the partition clause:

```
select id, date_weekly_list, rank() over (order by date_weekly_list desc)
from my_table
```

Otherwise you will rank the dates per date, and as you have discovered, all dates will have rank 1. If you want to get rid of gaps, use:

```
select id, date_weekly_list, dense_rank() over (order by date_weekly_list desc)
from my_table
```

Comment: Excellent thanks @Lennart, I hadn't seen that use of the analytical functions before without partition by. Dense rank was what I was looking for.